# jqgrid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

my jqgrid is working fine.but one problem is by default jqgrid is displaying all records even if page size is 2 or 4.. and it is showing page 1 of 0.
how to change this.
please answer this.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript where you setup the jqGrid, what do you have for these items:

```
rowNum: 20,
rowList: [10, 20, 30],
```